# Access SQL IF statement failing

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

Whats wrong with this IF statement? It appears to follow the criteria for a IF, but will not run

```
    SELECT Account, SUM(IF dbo_ADT.type = "wager" 
AND - dbo_ADT.amount > 0 then - dbo_ADT.amount 
ElseIf dbo_ADT.type = "cancel" THEN
     - dbo_ADT.amount elseIf dbo_ADT.type = "winnings" 
THEN - dbo_ADT.refund ELSE 0 END IF) AS Handle
FROM dbo_ADT
```

Comment: There is no `IF` statement in JetSQL, use `IIF` function

Comment: IFF does not allow for ElseIf, any suggestions for elseif?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access SQL does not support the `if...then...else`syntax (in sql, it's of course supported in vba) but you can use the `iif(condition, "value if true", "value if false")` to accomplish the same thing if you nest the `iif`statements. I think your query should be written as:

```
SELECT 
    Account, 
    SUM(
        IIF(
            dbo_ADT.type = "wager" AND - dbo_ADT.amount > 0,
            - dbo_ADT.amount, 
            IIF(
                dbo_ADT.type = "cancel",  
                - dbo_ADT.amount, 
                IIF(dbo_ADT.type = "winnings", dbo_ADT.refund,  0)
                )
            )
        ) AS Handle
FROM dbo_ADT
GROUP BY Account
```

I might have mixed up the nesting (although I believe it's correct), so you'll have to check that you get the expected result (especially for the `else` condition), but you should get the idea I hope.

I also added a `group by`clause that's needed when you use aggregate functions.